# Prove that $\sum_{n=M}^\infty\frac{1}{n(\ln n) (\ln \ln n) (\ln \ln \ln n)}$ is convergent by Cauchy Condensation Test.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f(n)=\dfrac{1}{n(\ln n) (\ln \ln n) (\ln \ln \ln n)}$

So, $2^n f(2^n) = \dfrac{1}{2^n (\ln 2^n) (\ln \ln 2^n) (\ln \ln \ln 2^n)}$

$= \dfrac{1}{2^n (n \ln2) (\ln n \ln2) (\ln \ln n \ln2)}$

I don't know what to conclude from here. Please help!

Comment: You might one to use the test twice or thrice.

Comment: You figure out the starting point of the series, i.e. the value of $M$ :-)

Comment: An error in the second equation. You forgot to cancel that $2^n$.

Comment: The series is not convergent.

Comment: @JuliánAguirre How do I prove that? Can you please elaborate a little? :)

Comment: See my new answer.

Answer (score 5):

The series is not convergent. To show it use the integral test. Let
$$
f(x)=\frac{1}{x(\ln x) (\ln \ln x) (\ln \ln \ln x)},\quad x\ge M>e^{e^e}
$$
$f$ is decreasing and
$$
\int_M^\infty f(x)\,dx=\ln\ln\ln\ln x\Bigr|_M^\infty=\infty.
$$

The same argument shows that
$$
\sum_{n=M}^\infty\frac{1}{n(\ln n) (\ln \ln n) (\ln \ln \ln n)^p}
$$
converges if $p>1$.

Answer (score 2):

You can use logarithm identities to change your expression to
$$
g(n) = \dfrac{1}{(\ln 2) n (\ln\ln 2 + \ln n)\ln (\ln 2 + \ln n)}
$$
Now you can apply the test again
$$
h(n) = 2^{n}g(2^n)
= \dfrac{2^n}{(\ln 2) 2^n (\ln\ln 2 + \ln(2^n))\ln(\ln\ln 2 + \ln(2^n))}
$$ and continue simplifying.  You will probably need to apply the test a third time.  You might also want to use bounding arguments such as $\ln\ln x \le \ln(\ln\ln 2 + x) \le 2 \ln\ln x$ for suitably large $x$ in order to try and simplify the expression further.